# Getting Week Of Date (Week Beginning) in Hive

Tags: hive, week-number

I currently have a code that takes a date and returns a Sunday Start date. What I want is to get a Monday start date instead like the weekofyear() function.

Below is my current code where evt_time is my datetime variable:

```
date_sub(evt_time,pmod(datediff(to_date(evt_time),'1900-01-07'),7))
```

For instance, I would want 6/4/2018-6/10/2018 to be group into 6/4/2018.

Comment: what format is evt_time in? yyyy-MM-dd or something else?

Comment: @VamsiPrabhala its yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss (2018-02-20 23:50:35)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the weekday with `u` argument and then use arithmetic to get the week start date as Monday.

```
select date_add(to_date(evt_time)
                ,1-cast(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(to_date(evt_time),'yyyy-MM-dd'),'u') as int))
```